# node.js volver a funcion javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs

espero me puedan ayudar con lo siguiente:
Tengo este formulario que llama una función en node (con formidable) que procesa la información de un archivo excel y guarda los datos en una base de datos...

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id='formid' action='/api/cargaDatos/'>
 <input type="file" name="file">
 <button type="submit" value="Upload">Cargar Archivo</button>
</form>
```

El proceso lo hace correctamente, pero quisiera de alguna forma mostrar un resumen del proceso con los datos almacenados y fallidos, retornando variables a un archivo con funciones en javascript para trabajar con el DOM dentro del mismo HTML que realizó la llamada.

Se puede hacer ? o que alternativas tengo ?
Les agradezco cualquier tip que puedan darme

Codigo Node:

```
cargaDatos(req, res) {
   1. Abro el archivo excel
   2. proceso los datos
   3. los guardo en una BD
   4. obtengo cantidad de datos buenos y malos
   Como muestro estos resultados en la página
   Call MuestraResultados(buenos, malos);
}
```

(ya se que Call no llama a la funcion, es solo para mostrar lo que me gustaría hacer)

JS:

```
function MuestraResultados(buenos, malos){
   $('#texto').Text('Datos correctos: '+buenos);
   $('#texto1').Text('Datos erroneos: '+malos)
}
```

Comment: Hola Rodrigo, has puesto las etiquetas [tag:javascript] y [tag:nodejs], pero no estás mostrando más que HTML (que parece lo menos importante en tu problema). Te aconsejo que intentes explicar el escenario usando tu código en NodeJs

Comment: La verdad no logro entender lo que quieres hacer. ¿A qué llamas ***el proceso***? Por otro lado, ¿qué quieres manipular del DOM? ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de lo que necesitas hacer? Saludos

Comment: Proceso: leer el contenido de la planilla excel, sacar los datos y guardarlo en la base de datos, de aquí saco datos buenos (grabados) y datos malos (sin grabar). estas variables con datos buenos y malos los quiero mostar en la página. Con manipular con el DOM me refiero a: $('#texto').Text('Datos correctos: '+buenos); $('#texto').Text('Datos erroneos: '+malos). Como paso las variables buenos y malos.